# Kubernetes network management - I have 20 worker nodes and wanted to establish a tcp connectivity to external system which is beyond firewall

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-networking

I have 20 worker nodes and wanted to establish a tcp connectivity to external system which is beyond firewall. Now I've got firewall opened for all 20 worker nodes (using node IP)

for every cluster - I need to get firewall access for all my worker nodes as my TCP connector pod is not having node affinitiy. Is there a better way to manage this scenario?

#kubernetes#k8s #service #network

Comment: set nodeAffinity/nodeSelector for tcp connector pod to always get scheduled on one/few nodes , in that way you just need to edit firewall only on those nodes .

Comment: another way would be to expose your tcp connector pod via a NodePort service and setup a loadbalancer which is available from outside routing to your tcp connector pod. that way you would potentially only need one firewall rule enabling access from outside to the lb